# memberOf values from inherited groups and roles / filtering

Tags: active-directory, ldap, filtering, openldap, ldap-query

I'm very new to LDAP and trying to setup inherited model for user logins with access level specific to department, etc.

Example schema would look like this:

```
    DN: dc=domain,dc=com

      /cn=people           (groupOfNames)
        /joe               (inetOrgPerson)
        /alex              (inetOrgPerson)
        /nick              (inetOrgPerson)
        /boss              (inetOrgPerson)
        /qaJane            (inetOrgPerson)
        /analystBob        (inetOrgPerson)

      /ou=groups           (organizationalUnit)
        /developers        (groupOfNames)
          member: uid=joe,cn=people,dc=domain,dc=com
          member: uid=nick,cn=people,dc=domain,dc=com

        /testers           (groupOfNames)
          member: uid=qaJane,cn=people,dc=domain,dc=com

        /projectManagers   (groupOfNames)
          member: uid=alex,cn=people,dc=domain,dc=com

        /analysts          (groupOfNames)
          member: uid=boss,cn=people,dc=domain,dc=com
          member: uid=analystBob,cn=people,dc=domain,dc=com

      /ou=applications     (organizationalUnit)
        /gitlab            (groupOfNames)
          member: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com
          member: cn=projectManagers,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com

        /redmine           (groupOfNames)
          member: cn=testers,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com
          member: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com
          member: cn=projectManagers,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com

        /nfs               (groupOfNames)
          member: cn=analysts,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com
          member: cn=projectManagers,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com
```

**in short, it could be described like this:**

1. Many users
2. Few groups (developer, manager, analyst, boss, etc.)
3. Some groups include other groupes (ie: projectManagers are included in developers)
4. Few applications.
5. Applications include groups and / or users

*What is a proper way to make a user search for login and consider user inheritance between all groups?*

Ie. if I want to log in user into gitlab - filter like this, would work only for direct inclusion (if user is included directly into the object that I filter against, but it won't work for group inclusion):
**(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=cn=redmine,ou=applications,dc=domain,dc=com))**

Answer (score 1):

You will need to perform a search similar to":

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:cn=redmine,ou=applications,dc=domain,dc=com)
```

From [Active Directory Group Related Searches](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches)

Comment: what is that number in the filter query?   >>>>    memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:      how do i find the correct value that i have to use in my case?

Comment: This is the OID of an Extended Search Filter. It would not change for the search required. It is Microsoft Active Directory specific though.

Comment: Would you be able to tell the value that I would need to use with openldap / slapd server?

Comment: so not a solution in my case? or is this the direction that i need to research to get it working with openldap? Thanks

Comment: If NOT using Microsoft Active Directory, you will need to loop through all nested Group values to find all Members.